# Java: GC Overhead when handling multiple files and best way to store them

Tags: java, postgresql, file, storage

I have two questions here. We store a huge amount of xml files in a postgres database, as bytea. For small users, there is no problem and we can handle all the files

A user can download all his xml's in a zip file. We then retrieve all files from database (around 5000 xml files with 15kb each), zip all the files and return to frontend.

The problem is that for that amount of files we are having GC Overhead, and the system goes down sometimes.

Is there a better way to handle those files?
If it is ok, how can we avoid the GC Overhead when retrieving all files?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but `text` or `xml` would be the more appropriate type to store XML content

Comment: thanks! I'll consider the change. We have a table that stores multiple file types for the same user, that's why we use byte[].

Comment: The Postgres JDBC driver loads the entire result set into memory by default. But you can configure it, to not do that: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor maybe that would help